# Explanation on a homework problem

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, econometrics, stata, heteroscedasticity

[image]

I was wondering if I could get help explaining this homework problem. The figure looks homoskedastic and I believe it has something to do with an assumption with it's criteria, but am unsure how to move forward.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You think that plot shows constant variance?

Comment: It is difficult to judge constant variance or not from that fig, because of all the overplotting hides the data density  ... @Dave:

Comment: @Kjetil Nevertheless, because this is a textbook question, its *intention* that the plot be interpreted as (strong) heteroscedasticity is clear.